# SharePoint 2013 Workflow not sending emails

Tags: email, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I've been trying fix this issue, on a new installation of SharePoint 2013 on a standalone server, for a couple of days now. I'm getting the "Internal status:Suspended" error on all the workflows I run:

```
RequestorId: 8e9ad795-7a8f-9a68-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled  
exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. 
Exception details: System.ArgumentException: AssignedTo at  Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at 
System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance,  
ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at     
  System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

I have found several articles that don't quite seem to solve the problem:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462.aspx#section2

http://sp2013.pro/category/error/wf-cancelssuspends/

The problem exists when I create both SP 2013 workflows and SP 2010 workflows. The OOTB Approval workflow does send emails correctly though, so I know that the mail server is working. I've tried an approval process from within the a custom workflow and that fails... So the problem, I'd assume, lies somewhere within the SharePoint Designer Workflow creation and the server.

The workflows will run up until the point of an email as I've have tested several variable changes and logged the progress to history.

Other things that I have done:
-Full profile synchronization
-SMTP server set up to allow anonymous and relay using only itself

UPDATE: I've just discovered that the workflow seems to have  to crash in custom columns within calendar events and also when you manually add a user to the workflow, conversely... a standard custom list will send an email to a manually inputted address and gives the following error before failing when using a custom people/group field:

```
Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute.  
Details of last request: HTTP BadRequest to 
http://domain/_vti_bin/client.svc/sp.utilities.utility.SendEmail
```

And then suspends itself with a similar message to original issue:

```
Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the    
workflow instance. Exception details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value 
cannot be null. Parameter name: Input at      Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Comment: Look this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/62031/sharepoint-2013-sharepoint-designer-workflow-gets-canceled